# Google Sheet cell value does not match

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to compare to cell in google sheet. Both the cell contains Value "Saturday".

`Cell A1 = TEXT(WEEKDAY(N1),"dddd") value is "Saturday"`

`Cell A2 = =B2 value is "Saturday"`

but when I compare both `=IF(A1=A2,"TRUE","FALSE")` Result is `FALSE`. I tried changing both cell to plain text but it did not work. Any solution?

Comment: Please include a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

This formula returns true so I cannot replicate what you are saying: `=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("5/30/20")),"dddd")="Saturday"`

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I found a mistake in my sheet and got it resolved.